# Creating Dropbox like DMG package

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, dmg

Does anyone suggest a freeware tool/script/manual_way of creating Dropbox like DMG - [image]

Need to ask couple of questions --

- I want double clicking the Folder-Icon should copy the folder(which would contain installer and uninstaller .app files of my application) into the system's /Applications folder.

Solution -- This has been solved using Applescript and changing icon of that applescript file to the folder-icon(i.e double clicking that script will move our folder(which would be present in a hidden folder) to /Applications.Any suggestions for second and third part?

- Is it possible to show hyperlink of actual dropbox.com to actually open it's website?
- And how we can customize volume's/Drive icon?

Comment: I use [DMG Canvas](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/dmg-canvas/id406067998?mt=12) for this.

Comment: @Cory Is it possible to show hyperlink of actual dropbox.com to actually open it's website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a way to do it by reading this: [Packaging a Mac OS X Application Using a DMG » asmaloney.com](http://asmaloney.com/2013/07/howto/packaging-a-mac-os-x-application-using-a-dmg/)

I believe you can also use the trick of naming a shellscript file `something.command` in order to make it double clickable, (but maybe it will open the terminal, -I haven't tried it).

Comment: Is it possible to show hyperlink of actual dropbox.com to actually open it's website?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you can make a webloc file. (Drag the url from Safari onto the Finder Desktop, or a Finder window and it should be saved as a webloc file. You should also be able to make a shell script with a 'command' suffix containing something like "open 'http://dropbox.com' in addition to the shebang, and it must also be made executable with chmod ugo+x (to be sure).

Comment: Thanks Somewhat helpful